# STM32F429 ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE TOOL AI_DATA_FORMAT_UQ NOT FOUND

Tags: eclipse, artificial-intelligence, stm32f4discovery, cubemx

I am studying on artificial intelligence with STM32F429. I generate the code with CubeMX for SystemWorkbench. CubeMX generated code has **AI_DATA_FORMAT_UQ** named macro but it has not defined anywhere. I mean;

```
#define AI_DATA_FORMAT_SQ \
   (AI_DATA_FORMAT_UQ|AI_FMT_SET_SIGN(1))
```

AI_DATA_FORMAT_UQ isn't defined anywhere else. Do you have an idea how to find this value? or is it possible to omit it?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to define it on a more global scope.

Comment: OK but how to define it? what is the value? is it enough just write 
#define AI_DATA_FORMAT_UQ . or it needs a value ?